# How to limit connections to a single client on a TcpNioServerConnectionFactory?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration

I currently have a Spring Integration application which is utilizing a number of TCP inbound and outbound adapter combinations for message handling. Each Inbound Adapter in these combinations uses a `TcpNioServerConnectionFactory`. I want these connection factories to be configured in a way that only a single client can establish a connection to the corresponding port at a time. Any additional connections attempted on the given port need to be rejected until the current client connection is either dropped or removed.

Through some initial research, I have come across the [`Multi Accept`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/TcpNioServerConnectionFactory.html#setMultiAccept-boolean-) property on the `TcpNioServerConnectionFactory` which seems promising. Is setting this property to false going to accomplish what I need or is there more that needs to be done to ensure the connection factories will handle connections as I need them to?

Comment: Close the listening socket immediately you accept a new connection; reopen it when you close that connection; and ignore anyone who tells you to set the listen backlog to zero or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; that property is unrelated, it is about prioritizing reads over accepting new connections.

You can capture connection open events and immediately close the additional connection(s); here's a simple boot app as an example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So59429748Application {


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So59429748Application.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So59429748Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNioServerConnectionFactory server() {
        return new TcpNioServerConnectionFactory(1234);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void connectionChecker(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event) {
        int connections = server().getOpenConnectionIds().size();
        if (event.getConnectionFactoryName().equals("server")
                && connections > 1) {
            logger.info(String.format("Too many connections (%d); closing %s", connections, event.getConnectionId()));
            server().closeConnection(event.getConnectionId());
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
            server().registerListener(msg -> false);
            server().start();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            Socket socket1 = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("localhost", 1234);
            Socket socket2 = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("localhost", 1234);
            logger.info("EOF on second socket:" + socket2.getInputStream().read());
            socket1.close();
        };
    }
}
```

> 2019-12-20 13:50:18.842  INFO 86323 --- [pool-1-thread-1] com.example.demo.So59429748Application   : Too many connections (2); closing localhost:49562:1234:b4d65f24-158c-4784-87dd-9b5e875aa08a
>
> 2019-12-20 13:50:18.843  INFO 86323 --- [           main] com.example.demo.So59429748Application   : EOF on second socket:-1

Comment: Thanks for the response Gary. This looks like it should do the trick for what I need. Need sometime to implement and validate what I need is accomplished. Will mark as the accepted answer once that is completed.